# Telegram Bot (coded in python) integration with AWS API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, telegram-bot, api-gateway

I just built a telegram bot using the python-telegram-bot package. I am trying to integrate it with AWS API Gateway such that **every time user sends a message, it triggers & runs the Lambda function**. I have set up the API gateway according to the instructions in this [link](https://github.com/lesterchan/telegram-bot). However, when I send message to the bot, the function doesn't get triggered & I don't receive any messages in return. It works though when I manually enter the "Invoke URL" of API gateway, ie. the API is indeed triggering the Lambda function, just that **the telegram bot is not triggering the API even though I have already set the webhook**. specifically, I used: `curl --data "url=<INVOKE_URL>" "https://api.telegram.org/bot<ACCESS_TOKEN>/setWebhook"`

I would really appreciate if someone could advise me on how to integrate API gateway to trigger Lambda code for telegram bot. It is my first Python project actually, but deployment on AWS has been such a huge hurdle!

```
import requests
import re
import os

def start(update, context):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="Beep boop dog! Type /bop to receive dog pics.")

def get_url():
    contents = requests.get('https://random.dog/woof.json').json()
    url = contents['url']
    return url

def get_image_url():
    allowed_extension = ['jpg','jpeg','png']
    file_extension = ''
    while file_extension not in allowed_extension:
        url = get_url()
        file_extension = re.search("([^.]*)$",url).group(1).lower()
    return url

def bop(update, context):
    url = get_image_url()
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=url)

def main(event, context):
    TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start',start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('bop',bop))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why do you want to involve Lambda in this? What do you want the Lambda function to do?

Comment: What would you suggest I use instead? I wanted to use Lambda bc I don't have that many users and I want to activate my code only when there are requests coming in.

Comment: What do you want your code to do? You get the requests... and then what? You are trying to send a message to the opposite user... you are trying to send the message json object to a database... what exactly is your plan? Usually code like this is written in the source code. Lambda functions are beneficial if you need to update the OS or update NPM or something like that.

Comment: Yes, the architecture I have in mind is: user sends request to bot, it gets pushed to API, API triggers lambda function to run so that response can be sent back to user. What do you mean by source code, sorry? Which AWS service do you recommend I use instead? EC2? CodeBuild? Thanks, appreciate your help!

Comment: 1. What type of request is the user sending?
2. Why are you involving a bot in this, why not just let the user request go straight to the API, why are you complicating it with a middleman? 
3. I don't see any code here on "pushing it to the API" as you said.

Comment: If I were you, I would just set up an free tier t2.micro ec2 instance and turn on scaling if you need more. Remember to put in a ec2 user data script. Lambda can also be used for serverless requests, similar to an Ec2 and it doesn't run all the time. However, in this example.... I think about just using ec2 because it is easier to set up. And just use the AWS console to log into your ec2 instance (remember to use the username ec2-user@"ec2InstanceIP". You can also SSH into your ec2 if you want. Install your node, or backend, and then install pm2 or nodemon to make sure it runs all the time.

Comment: And just use the AWS console to log into your ec2 instance (remember to use the username ec2-user@"ec2InstanceIP". You can also SSH into your ec2 if you want.

Comment: Thanks @EvanErickson, tried out the EC2 method and it is a much smoother process. I wasn't sure when to use Lambda and EC2 and was using an unnecessarily complicated solution so thanks for letting me know! Also learnt to run it on nohup. Not sure how that differs from pm2 / nodemon, so lmk if you can.

Comment: Nodemon / pm2 just allows you to run node in the background and make sure it continually runs. I'm glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used EC2 with process below.
Set locale before I could invoke ‘sudo yum install’

[on EC2]

```
sudo vi /etc/environment
```

appended `LANG=en_US.utf-8 /n LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8`

```
sudo yum install python 37
curl -0 https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --user
pip install <package> --user
```

[on localhost]

```
scp -i beepboopdog.pem script.py ec2-user@<ec2-ip>.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user
```

[on EC2] Nohup: for script to run after terminating session

```
nohup python3 script.py &
ps -ef to list processID
kill <processID>
```